# When I refresh the page, the popup window is visible for a second.

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Script**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".aboutBtn").click(function () {
            $(".aboutContent").slideToggle("slow");
   });

  $(".contact").click(function () {
            $(".aboutContent").slideToggle("slow");
      });
   });
```

**Html**

```
<article class="aboutBtn">ABOUT</article>
```

**Css**

```
 .aboutBtn{
       width:85px; 
       padding:5px 0px 5px 10px; 
       background-color:#d8531e;
       cursor:pointer;
       color:#ffffff; 
       font-size:20px; 
       text-transform:uppercase;
       position:relative;top:-48px; 
       font-family:"Segoe UI Light";
  }
```

---

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking for here.  What pop-up window are you referring to?  Can you provide more context around what the issue is that you're having?

Answer (score 2):

Hide the popup with your stylesheet.

CSS:

```
.aboutContent{
  display: none;
}
```